# Rosetta error with docker on M1 Pro MacBook

Tags: docker, arm, apple-m1

```
59.35 
59.35 2023-08-17 03:27:46 (15.7 MB/s) - ‘/usr/local/bin/swagger’ saved [22016032/22016032]
59.35 
59.36 rosetta error: failed to open elf at /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
59.36  ./build/build_swagger.sh: line 6:   100 Trace/breakpoint trap   swagger flatten "${scriptdir}"/../server/source/swagger-specs/index.yaml -o "${scriptdir}"/../server/source/swagger-specs/api.yaml --format=yaml --with-flatten=full
------
Dockerfile:42
--------------------
  40 |     COPY --from=crypt-dep /src/crypt/b64utils.h /dist/b64utils.h
  41 |     COPY --from=crypt-dep /src/crypt/cryptlib.h /dist/cryptlib.h
  42 | >>> RUN ./build/build_go_deps.sh
  43 |     
  44 |     RUN chmod 755 /go/src/lakehouse/bin/restapi-server
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c ./build/build_go_deps.sh" did not complete successfully: exit code: 133
make: *** [docker] Error 1
```

II was making a build of project, it contains docker containers. Using M1 Pro MacBook. Any solutions for this rosetta error ? Is it associated with docker support in ARM platform?

Edit :

Contents of build_go_deps.sh

[image]

Comment: what is `build_go_deps.sh` supposed to do? can you add it to the question?

Comment: @RickRackow
Updated with contents of file

The script is a bash script that installs dependencies and builds a final binary for a Go project. It installs the following dependencies:

- wget
- tar
- git
- xz
- ca-certificates
- IBM DB2 ODBC driver
- UPX
- Swagger


It then builds the final binary by running two other scripts:
- build_swagger.sh
- build_binary.sh


The final binary is built for Linux.

Comment: does the same happen when you explicitly set the `--platform` flag like `docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 my-cool-image:latest .` ?